# When I try to open my python game, it crashes immediately

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

My python game crashes immediately when I try to open it. It is a frappy bird game clone. I made it using Python 3.7.7, Pygame 2.0.0 and Visual Studio Code IDE. The following error comes:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "c:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\Go Alien Go\Go Alien Go.py", line 190, in <module>
>    pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','0.png')).convert_alpha(),
> FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
> ```

I am trying to solve this problem from last three days, I searched about it all over but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

Here is my code:

```
import random 
import sys 
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
import os

pygame.init()

FPS = 32
SCREENWIDTH = 289
SCREENHEIGHT = 511
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
GROUNDY = SCREENHEIGHT * 0.4
GAME_SPRITES = {}
GAME_SOUNDS = {}
PLAYER = os.path.join('data','alien.jpg')
BACKGROUND = os.path.join('data','background.jpg')
PIPE = os.path.join('data','pipe.jpg')

def welcomeScreen():
    

    playerx = int(SCREENWIDTH/5)
    playery = int((SCREENHEIGHT - GAME_SPRITES['player'].get_height())/2)
    messagex = int((SCREENWIDTH - GAME_SPRITES['message'].get_width())/2)
    messagey = int(SCREENHEIGHT*0.13)
    basex = 0
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            
            elif event.type==KEYDOWN and (event.key==K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
                return
            else:
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['background'], (0, 0))    
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['player'], (playerx, playery))    
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['message'], (messagex,messagey ))    
                SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['base'], (basex, GROUNDY))    
                pygame.display.update()
                FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def mainGame():
    score = 0
    playerx = int(SCREENWIDTH/5)
    playery = int(SCREENWIDTH/2)
    basex = 0

    
    newPipe1 = getRandomPipe()
    newPipe2 = getRandomPipe()

    
    upperPipes = [
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH+200, 'y':newPipe1[0]['y']},
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH+200+(SCREENWIDTH/2), 'y':newPipe2[0]['y']},
    ]
    
    lowerPipes = [
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH+200, 'y':newPipe1[1]['y']},
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH+200+(SCREENWIDTH/2), 'y':newPipe2[1]['y']},
    ]

    pipeVelX = -4

    playerVelY = -9
    playerMaxVelY = 10
    playerMinVelY = -8
    playerAccY = 1

    playerFlapAccv = -8 
    playerFlapped = False 


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
                if playery > 0:
                    playerVelY = playerFlapAccv
                    playerFlapped = True


        crashTest = isCollide(playerx, playery, upperPipes, lowerPipes) 
        if crashTest:
            return     

        playerMidPos = playerx + GAME_SPRITES['player'].get_width()/2
        for pipe in upperPipes:
            pipeMidPos = pipe['x'] + GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][0].get_width()/2
            if pipeMidPos<= playerMidPos < pipeMidPos +4:
                score +=1
                print(f"Your score is {score}") 


        if playerVelY <playerMaxVelY and not playerFlapped:
            playerVelY += playerAccY

        if playerFlapped:
            playerFlapped = False            
        playerHeight = GAME_SPRITES['player'].get_height()
        playery = playery + min(playerVelY, GROUNDY - playery - playerHeight)

        # move pipes to the left
        for upperPipe , lowerPipe in zip(upperPipes, lowerPipes):
            upperPipe['x'] += pipeVelX
            lowerPipe['x'] += pipeVelX

    
        if 0<upperPipes[0]['x']<5:
            newpipe = getRandomPipe()
            upperPipes.append(newpipe[0])
            lowerPipes.append(newpipe[1])


        if upperPipes[0]['x'] < -GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][0].get_width():
            upperPipes.pop(0)
            lowerPipes.pop(0)
        

        SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['background'], (0, 0))
        for upperPipe, lowerPipe in zip(upperPipes, lowerPipes):
            SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][0], (upperPipe['x'], upperPipe['y']))
            SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][1], (lowerPipe['x'], lowerPipe['y']))

        SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['base'], (basex, GROUNDY))
        SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['player'], (playerx, playery))
        myDigits = [int(x) for x in list(str(score))]
        width = 0
        for digit in myDigits:
            width += GAME_SPRITES['numbers'][digit].get_width()
        Xoffset = (SCREENWIDTH - width)/2

        for digit in myDigits:
            SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['numbers'][digit], (Xoffset, SCREENHEIGHT*0.12))
            Xoffset += GAME_SPRITES['numbers'][digit].get_width()
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def isCollide(playerx, playery, upperPipes, lowerPipes):
    if playery> GROUNDY - 25  or playery<0:
        return True
    
    for pipe in upperPipes:
        pipeHeight = GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][0].get_height()
        if(playery < pipeHeight + pipe['y'] and abs(playerx - pipe['x']) < GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][0].get_width()):
            return True

    for pipe in lowerPipes:
        if (playery + GAME_SPRITES['player'].get_height() > pipe['y']) and abs(playerx - pipe['x']) < GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][0].get_width():
            return True

    return False

def getRandomPipe():
    
    pipeHeight = GAME_SPRITES['pipe'][0].get_height()
    offset = SCREENHEIGHT/3
    y2 = offset + random.randrange(0, int(SCREENHEIGHT - GAME_SPRITES['base'].get_height()  - 1.2 *offset))
    pipeX = SCREENWIDTH + 10
    y1 = pipeHeight - y2 + offset
    pipe = [
        {'x': pipeX, 'y': -y1}, 
        {'x': pipeX, 'y': y2} 
    ]
    return pipe






if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    pygame.init() 
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Go Alien Go by Aaishwarya Halder')
    GAME_SPRITES['numbers'] = ( 
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','0.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','1.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','2.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','3.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','4.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','5.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','6.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','7.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','8.png')).convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','9.png')).convert_alpha(),
    )

    GAME_SPRITES['message'] =pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','message.png')).convert_alpha()
    GAME_SPRITES['base'] =pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data','base.png')).convert_alpha()
    GAME_SPRITES['pipe'] =(pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.image.load( PIPE).convert_alpha(), 180), 
    pygame.image.load(PIPE).convert_alpha()
    )


    GAME_SPRITES['background'] = pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND).convert()
    GAME_SPRITES['player'] = pygame.image.load(PLAYER).convert_alpha()

    while True:
        welcomeScreen() 
        mainGame()
```

Comment: The error is quite obvious, does `data/0.png` exist ?

Comment: I think Ôrel and Guseyn013 have your actual question covered, but I also want to take this opportunity to evangelize for Python's [Pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/) module. I don't know about you, but I'd much rather type `data = Path('data')` once, followed by `data / '0.png'` etc., rather than the repeated and harder-to-read `os.path.join('data','0.png')`.

Comment: Since you're using relative paths, you should check [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=getcwd#os.getcwd) since your files are expected to be relative to what's your current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs either because the file `0.png` does not exist or because it is not in the same directory.
If the latter is the case, then you will have to provide the full file path for the file. It can be done using terminal/cmd and the key word `pwd` when you are in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

`0.png` doesnt exist xD. If it does, you haven't placed it in the right directory.

Comment: can anyone explain why we take if pipeMidPos<= playerMidPos < pipeMidPos +4: in the above code. It does not work well if we take something else instead of 4.